# substr_replace does not replace in cyrillic

Tags: php

I have the code

```php
<?php
    $location = 'Болгария';
    if (substr("$location", -1) == ('я')) {
        echo substr_replace("$location","и",-1);
    }
    else if (substr("$location", -1) == ('и')) {
        echo substr_replace("$location","ах",-1);
    }
?>
```

The idea is to change last letter depend on `$location`, but it does not work.

If I change Cyrillic with English or numbers - all works okay. So it's a problem with Russian letters.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: The problem isn't `substr_replace()`. None of the `substr()` checks are succeeding.

Comment: You need to use `mb_substr()`. There's no `mb_substr_replace()`, you'll need to write your own equivalent, I think.

Comment: There is no direct mb_string replace method, however, there is a mb_ereg_replace method.